# ajax success function not getting called in java script

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am working with `Spring MVC architecture`,in my application I have written controllers these are nothing but my services which returns json objects as a response.

Now I am trying to call that controller using ajax call in javascript.
I have written ajax call for one of my controller and am passing JSON object from my client side as it is a POST request.
In that ajax call every statement get executed correctly till the `content-type` ,
but when it comes to success function it gets redirected to error function directly without executing the success function.

I have gone through all suggested links but still I am stuck on the same error.

Can any one help me to get the solution.
Here is code am using :

```
function postRequest(postUrl,jsonData)
{
var result;
$.ajax({    
    url: postUrl, 
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true, // enable this
    data: jsonData, 
    dataType: 'json', 
    traditional : true,
   // processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: (function (data) 
     {          
        alert(data);
            result = data;
                alert("In success");
     }),
    error: function (errorThrown)
    {
        alert("In error");
        return errorThrown;
    }

});

return result;
}
```

This is my JSON object

```
{
  "description":"This is test",
  "price":11.0,
  "code":"11"
}
```

I am getting these two errors :

```
Object { readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/v.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 11 more… } RequestResponse.js:52:6
```

Above error I received in `errorThrown object`.and below is one more error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.1.100:8080/FINEXERP_Server/codePrice/save. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

Comment: what is the error you get in the error: function() ?
Modify your error callback to  
error : function(xhr, status, errThrown) {
  console.log(xhr, status, errThrown);
}
check what error u get.

Comment: `async: false,` is always a bad idea, that's not how must work ajax request and this is btw deprecated

Comment: `when it comes to success function it gets redirected to error function directly without executing the success function` So the request doesn't success but failed. Check error message

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
function postRequest(postUrl,jsonData) {
  var result;
  $.ajax({    
    url: postUrl, 
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true, // enable this
    data: jsonData, 
    dataType: 'json', 
    traditional : true,
   // processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {          
        alert(data);
            result = data;
                alert("In success");
     },
    error: function (errorThrown) {
        alert("In error");
        return errorThrown;
    }

 });

 return result;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried your suggested modification but still same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to `stringify` you data like

```
data: JSON.stringify({'jsonData' : jsonData}),
```